# How can I dig a hold between two object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges, knife-tool

I have two models. Is there a way to make an Edge in one model by using another model's shape?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you "just" want to make an edge you could use the knife tool. If you want to cut the geometry you can use boolean modifier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can join the two objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>), go in *Edit* mode, select one of the two meshes and go into the header menu → *Face → Intersect (Knife)*:

[image]

It will create an edge along the intersection of the two meshes. Result:

[image]